# 2D Array: Alphabetical Sorting in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char **items
```

This is how I create my array. `items[0]` is the first string, `items[1]` is the second etc..
I want to sort those strings alphabetically, so for example:

```
c.bmp (items[0])
b.bmp (items[1])
a.bmp (items[2])
```

becomes:

```
a.bmp (items[0])
b.bmp (items[1])
c.bmp (items[2])
```

But when I do qsort: (where `i` is the number of strings)

```
qsort(items, i, (sizeof(char *)), cmp);
```

It does not end up in order. The order changes, but it is not alphabetical.

Here is my `cmp` function:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { 
    char** p1 = (char**) a;

    char** p2 = (char**) b;

    if( p1[1] > p2[1])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (p1[1] < p2[1])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no 2D array. A pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cmp` function is not comparing the strings, only their places in memory (even worse - the places in memory of things after them, i.e. `p1[1]` instead of `p1[0]`, which also produces undefined behavior when the last element of the array participates in comparison).

You can fix this by using `strcmp` inside your `cmp` after dereferencing the pointers passed into your code:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char** p1 = (char**) a;
    char** p2 = (char**) b;
    return strcmp(*p1, *p2);
}
```

Comment: `p1[1]` and `p2[1]` are *pointers*, which is what the original code was comparing.

Comment: @ScottHunter You are right, these are pointers. The code is not even comparing the initial characters. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I realized this a few minutes after posting.. My bad